# Google App Script: Set cell blank if time is older than one hour

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pExqHJQubnSPDKczkF9HMA2QN1cxTYmzyewQdugDRYs/edit#gid=1512058574

I have `normal` & `epoch time`:

[image]

I'm looking to clear `NormalTime` & `EpochTime` cells if they're older than one hour.

So I've written this script that deletes cells older than one hour:

```
function removeOldProcessTime() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Time");
  var processTime = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var now = new Date();
  var ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
  var oneHourAgo = now - ONE_HOUR;

      for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) 
    {
      if(processTime[i] < oneHourAgo)
      {
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1).setValue('');
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue('');
      }
    }
}
```

However, when I run, only row 8 is deleted:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Requirement:**
I'm looking to delete cells that are older than one hour.

Data:

```
NormalTime  EpochTime
8/24 11:27:34 AM    1566671254626
8/24 11:50:43 AM    1566672643507
8/24 3:27:34 PM 1566685654609
8/24 5:27:34 PM 1566692854531
8/24 6:27:34 PM 1566696454446
8/24 8:27:34 PM 1566703654460
8/24 9:27:34 PM 1566707254819
8/24 10:27:34 PM    1566710854416
```

Comment: Looks like I needed to format `column B` to number format of `0`. GAS automatically converts the cell into date and so in the script, it sees the `EpochTime` as normal formatted date and it had trouble converting it back to Epoch time

Comment: If solved, kindly add it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I needed to format `column B` to number format of `0`. GAS automatically converts the cell into date and so in the script, it sees the `EpochTime` as normal formatted date and it had trouble converting it back to `Epoch` time